# Fundamentals of electrical circuits. Practice problem 16.13 Network Stability

Tags: circuit-analysis, stability, calculation

[image]

I have this question from my Electrical Electronics textbook. After repeated efforts I still can't manage to solve it and the textbook doesn't provide enough information to be able to solve this question.

Comment: Did you try to simulate this circuit with SPICE? I used 1 µF and 10 ohms for the caps and resistances then set beta to -100.5m after setting a .IC=1 V to the right-side cap: it nicely diverges as expected. Here, I would determine the time constants of this second-order system in the form of \$D(s)=1+b_1s+b_2s^2\$ then set the whole thing under the form \$D(s)=1+\frac{s}{\omega_0Q}+\frac{s^2}{\omega_0^2}\$ then determine \$Q\$ and see how it goes negative, implying having poles in the right-half plane. There might be a faster way but that is what I would attempt. What did you try on your side?

Comment: You should actually find that one of the time constants has a factor equal to \$\tau_{12}=C_2\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R}+\beta}\$ in which \$\beta\$ is a transconductance and \$C_2\$ is the right-side capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

Let's redraw the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsOXGX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ignore \$C\$ on the left side. Given enough time it's an open circuit. Here KCL says \$\frac{v_i}{R}=\beta\,v_o\$ or \$v_i=\beta\,R\,v_o\$.

Ignore \$C\$ on the right side. Given enough time it's also an open circuit.  Here KCL says \$\frac{v_o}{R}=-\beta\,v_o\$ or \$\beta=-\frac1{R}\$.

Since the left side node voltage depends directly and entirely upon the right side node voltage, there's no point looking at the left side. It's a red herring.

Returning to the right side and thinking about when \$\beta=-\frac1{R}\$. Suppose \$v_o\$ moves more positive. Then \$\frac{v_o}{R}\$ increases and this is exactly met by \$I_y\$. But \$C\$ on the right also requires a current pointing in the same direction as \$\frac{v_o}{R}\$ and there's no source for that current. KCL is violated. So as a result of adding \$C\$ we know that \$\beta\ne -\frac1{R}\$.

The only way that there can be at least *some* current to supply the right side \$C\$ if the node voltage changes is to ensure that \$\frac{v_o}{R}\gt-\beta\,v_o\$. Or, \$\beta\gt -\frac1{R}\$.

But this also guarantees that on the right side \$v_o\to 0\:\text{V}\$, given time. And that will eventually also then mean \$v_i=0\:\text{V}\$, too.

Of course, we could have simply recognized that \$v_o= 0\:\text{V}\$ and \$v_i=0\:\text{V}\$ is and always was a solution.

And that's stable.

*(Note to self -- it's possible to add an answer to a question an hour later than when the question was closed. Might be a profound truth buried in that fact.)*

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, but I post it, so it maybe helps.

There is a current source ("Voltage controlled current source") and a voltage output.

There is a feedback, as the source is controlled by the output.
We can express Vo in terms of the source current as
\$Vo= -I*1/(1/R+j*wC)\$

Now you need some stability criteria like
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barkhausen_stability_criterion
, but I don't know enough about it. My guess is, that it's described in this very textbook of yours, maybe one or pages before the cited exercise.

It will allow you to write some inequality like
"I_feedbacked" / I < 1

With the help of the formulas

Vo=f(I) and
I = beta*Vo

you should be able to shorten the inequality to the given solution.